# create apex class test that have Data Type formula fields

Tags: apex, class

My code coverage for my trigger is only at 50%. I have 2 (Today_10_Trigger__c,Record_Type_Hidden__c) fields in my trigger criteria that are formulas therefore not writtable.

**This is my Trigger:**

```
     trigger RenewalUpdates on Account (before insert,before update) {

    List<Account > needsUpdate = new List<Account >();  

 for( Account accountId : Trigger.new)
 {
//  if( Trigger.oldMap.get( accountId ).Contract_End__c== Trigger.newMap.get( accountId ).Today_10_Trigger__c)
  if(accountId.Contract_End__c== accountId.Today_10_Trigger__c && accountId.Record_Type_Hidden__c== 'Agent' && accountId.Status__c == 'Active')
  {


        // do something here because your field are equal

        //accountId.End_Date_Trigger__c=system.today();
        accountId.Renewal_In_Progress__c=true;
        accountId.Status__c='Renewal In progress';
        accountId.Approval_Progress__c='Up For renewal';        

        needsUpdate .add(accountId);
        System.debug('Test=============');
  }
}

}
```

**And This is my Test Class:**

```
   @isTest
public class TestRenewalUpdates
{
    static testmethod void testAccount()
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.name='Test';
        acc.Contract_End__c= Date.newInstance( 2016,30,03 );
        //acc.Today_10_Trigger__c = Date.newInstance( 2016,30,03 );
        //acc.Record_Type_Hidden__c='Agent';

        acc.Status__c = 'Active';
        insert acc;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please post the formulas available in those two formula fields. It may help us to understand what that formula does and how to attain those values.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to 100% by changing the date for my end date.

```
acc.Contract_End__c=Date.today()+10;
```